# Requests.get in python3 not working. Need help to make it get data from all pages of a search query

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Code to get all data from URL in requests.get not working - it only retrieves one page's worth of data (30 records).  How do I have to modify my code to make sure I get data from all the pages?

```
NAEYCData = requests.get('http://families.naeyc.org/search_programs/results/0/NJ/0/100/0/0/0/us/0?page=')
openFile = open('NAEYCData', 'wb')
for chunk in NAEYCData.iter_content(100000):
    openFile.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 2):

The actual page only provides 30 results at a time. Each subsequent page is accessed with a different argument to `page` in the URL (the first page is `page=0`, the second is `page=1`, etc.).

You could download each page individually, but frankly, the better solution (for you and their server) is probably to download [the CSV linked to on the search results page](http://families.naeyc.org/programs/csv/CSV?attach=list) you're trying to grab, which contains the same information structured as a single CSV file, requiring fewer connections and less bandwidth to transfer, and is [easy to parse programmatically](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) (easier than HTML in general, and much easier than parsing nine separate HTML pages and gluing the results back together).

Comment: Completely agree with your approach.   Tried doing that as well, except I've never downloaded CSV files before (using a code).  Tried a few approaches I've seen on this site and elsewhere (including using urllib), but none seem to work so far.  Any suggestions on how to approach downloading the CSV?  Thanks.

Comment: @user6860460, you've to specify the complete file name. Like `NAEYCData.csv`.

Comment: @user6860460 please don't change the question after your first gets solved. The edit completely changed the qusetion and invalidated this answer. I've done a rollback. If you want to ask a new question, please create a new post. Don't edit this one.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - tried to download the CSV as you suggested in your response, but unable to do so.  Posted the code I used to download the CSV on March 17 and asked for help on why it wasn't doing the trick. No responses yet that resolved it.  Here's a link to that question in case you're able to help address it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333835/trying-to-download-a-csv-file-with-data-after-running-a-search-query-using-pytho/49334076#49334076.  If not, any further thoughts on how to download a page's worth of data without using a for loop that changes the argument for each page?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar: Would you have any ideas on my question above to ShadowRanger?