# Trying to download a csv file with data after running a search query using Python 3. Don't know if the code works

Tags: python, python-3.x, download

Is this the correct code to run the search query and download the resulting csv file (you have to click Download CSV on the website to download the file).  If not, how should i modify it and where should I look for the downloaded file?  In the default Downloads folder or elsewhere?

```
import requests, csv, urllib
from urllib import request    

URL = 'http://families.naeyc.org/programs/csv/CSV?attach=list'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
with open('file.csv','wb') as fx:
    fx.write(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new file with `open('file.csv','wb')` it is created in the same folder as your Python script file

Comment: In that case, this script doesn't download the file.  Any thoughts on how to modify it so it works?  Thanks.